# Design-Time validation of library

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a library that I would like to license and distribute.

I know how to license a class/library for runtime. I've done that several times, actually. I know how to license a user control. I've also done that several times.

What's got me stumped is how to license a library (that has no drag/drop user control or component) for development only. How do you license a library for design-time?

Any thoughts/hints?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally found the answer. This one isn't as apparent as I thought it would be.

Instead of looking for DesignTime or RunTime attributes, you need to see if a debugger is attached.

Drop this in the constructor (with the appropriate attributes on your class), and you're off and running!!

```
if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
{
    License L = LicenseManager.Validate(typeof(MyControl), this);
}
```

I hope this helps someone else with the same issue!!

--Jerry

Answer (score -1):

You could use LibraryManager.UsageMode to determine if you are running at design time.  I assume you wish to check for a debug run also from the answer you posted.

Comment: -1 `.UsageMode` will always return `LicenseUsageMode.RunTime`, unless the method containing this check (in the lib) is called from the design-time code of some other control/component, assuming the project even _has_ a design-time component.  (eg what about some other class library or console-app that's referencing this class lib?)