# execute method from referenced class library before build .NET application for license checking

Tags: c#, .net, build, licensing

I'm developing a class library which should be licensed to specific developer computers. There are no components so that the design time licensing checks can't be done.

This check is in fact unavailable for pure class libraries:

```
if( LicenseContext.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.Designtime ) ...
```

One has suggested to use Debugger.IsAttached to check if the lib is used on the developer machine:
[Design-Time validation of library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462853/design-time-validation-of-library)

But I'm looking after a solution on the build stage, so that the program won't build if the license is invalid (e.G. this machine is not licensed). Any suggestions?

Comment: "This check is in fact unavailable for pure class libraries".  Well, it's _available_ (ie it's still part of `System.dll`) :-)  It's just _meaningless_ I think, as `.UsageMode` will always return `LicenseUsageMode.RunTime`, unless the method containing this check (in your lib) is called from the design-time code of a control/component.

Comment: Will the lib be (freely) available to the consumers of the developers' application?  In which case, is there anything stopping the developer from just obtaining a free version of the lib and developing against that? +1 by the way... I'm interested to see what responses you get.

Comment: Maybe some variations with CodeContracts will help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is impossible or very hard to do license check in compile / build time. It is hard for you to force something to happen (like license check) in build time.

For licensing take a look at [Rhino Licensing](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/oss/rhino-licensing). Maybe you can make an obfuscated version without license check, and an normal version with a license check.

But any license protection can be hacked.

Comment: I will use IntelliLock and use Debugger.IsAttached to check hardware based licensing on debug.